# Adding instant search to wordpress page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to the site and to web development in general. I have a domain name, a hosting site, and wordpress installed. That took me most of a day. Now I'm trying to add this functionality to my site http://www.9lessons.info/2010/09/youtube-instant-search-with-jquery-and.html as a proof of concept before heavily modifying it.

The problem is that while I can paste that code into an HTML file and run it perfectly, I can't get my wordpress site to fire it off within a page no matter what I try. After spending a good 6 hours banging my head around with things like child templates, the function.php file, etc. etc. I still can't get it working. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom page template (http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) and adding the code there?

Comment: I may be wrong, but can't I not run javascript from within a PHP page?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. What ended up working is putting the script portion in a .js file within the theme directory, calling it using the functions.php in my child theme, and having the HTML input field and div tag in the body of the page.

Hopefully this can spare others the same pain I went through.